# how does the .render() function in react work internally?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I can define a component like this:

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello!</h1>;
  }
}
```

When I want to render this object in the Dom (or rather add it to the virtual DOM) I call

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Welcome />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

That means that at some point multiple `.render()` functions are nested inside of each other since we defined `return <h1>Hello!</h1>;` inside of the `.render()` function of `Welcome`. 
It also means that I can use the `.render()` method to render an Object to the DOM and to define a new react object.

This syntax is from the [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/rendering-elements.html)

Does `.render()` just render things to the virtual DOM **and** the nesting is resolved by React internally or is there more behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To understand render you have to understand how react works internally. To understand this in greater detail I would recoment reading [this](https://overreacted.io/react-as-a-ui-runtime/) but here is a quick overview:

Conceptually a react component is a just a function that returns an Object like this:

```
{
  type: 'button',
  props: {...} 
};
```

So the `render()` part of a class component just specifies what part of the component will be returned. The react virtual dom is made up of many of these object nested inside of each other (in props.children). React will start at the top object, turn it into an html node and render it to the dom, then do the same for all of its children etc.

Answer (score 1):

From [Rendering a Component](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html#rendering-a-component):

(updated to reflect your code)

```
class Welcome extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <h1>Hello!</h1>;
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(
  <Welcome />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

1. We call `ReactDOM.render()` with the `<Welcome />` element.
2. React calls the Welcome component with `{}` as the props.
3. Our Welcome component returns a `<h1>Hello!</h1>` element as the result.
4. React DOM efficiently updates the DOM to match `<h1>Hello</h1>`.

It may be beneficial to read up on the [React Life Cycle](http://projects.wojtekmaj.pl/react-lifecycle-methods-diagram/).